# Conditionally run function based on custom meta value?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, custom-field, hooks, post-meta, conditional-content

I’m looking for a way to conditionally display an image within certain Woocommerce hooks that I choose based on whether a value is true within a custom meta field for the products on my site.

For example, if my custom meta value for a product is “X”, then I print custom html (containing an image) for the Woocommerce hooks ‘woocommerce_product_additional_information’ and ‘woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item’. However if the meta value is empty, then no image is printed for a particular product post.

So far this is the code I've been trying to make work within my theme's functions.php file for a single hook. The 'add_action' function works for displaying images within a hook, but I can't figure out how to get the if statement to work.

```
if ( get_post_meta($post_id->ID, 'my-custom-meta-field', true) ) :

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', 'print_custom_html' );
 function
 print_custom_html
 (){ ?> <img src="image.jpg" alt="Image Name"> <?php }

endif;
```

**My questions:**

1. How can I conditionally run the 'add_action' function based on whether my custom product meta has a value of 'X' or not?
2. How can I customize my 'add_action' function to work with more than one Woocommerce hooks?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of conditionally adding an `add_action()` call, you can just add it and run the function it hooks to—its callback—conditionally instead.

For example:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', 'wpse407073_callback' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'wpse407073_callback' );

function wpse407073_callback( $product = null ) {
    if ( empty( $product ) ) {
        global $post;
        $product = $post;
    }
    if ( 'X' === get_post_meta( $product->ID, 'my-custom-meta-field', true ) ) {
        echo '<img src="image.jpg" alt="Image Name">';
    }
}
```

A few points:

- Having looked quickly at WooCommerce's code, `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` doesn't pass anything to the callback, and `woocommerce_product_additional_information` passed 1 parameter, `$product`, which I'm assuming is a custom post. That's why I added a check for an empty `$product` in the callback.
- This code hasn't been tested, and is meant as a possible starting point, not a finished product.
- If you have questions about WooCommerce's hooks, you should check with [WooCommerce's documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/) and/or their support team.

Comment: Thanks! With a few adjustments this solution worked perfectly.